# How to choose the direction of the control volume in fluid mechanics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Regarding this problem on conservation laws:
[image: Problem on Conservation Laws]

It seems logic to choose the control volume to follow the direction of the velocity field. I know that this implies a much simpler momentum conservation equation and so on, but is there any other reason for it to be that way? Is it the only way to choose the control volume or can we pick for instance a control volume that is completely straight along the x axis? I guess my question is: what are the thoughts that lead you to choose that specific control volume?

Answer (score 4):

You choose a control volume where it is easy to describe the flow through the boundary.

If you chose a rectangle along the XY axes, you would have an unknown amount of flow through the two sides in the X direction.

If you make the side of the control volume follow the streamlines, as in the picture, you know the flow through those sides is zero.